# Security: Restrict plugin access to file system and network

Tags: actionscript-3

In a plugin context (a swf loaded by an another swf), is there any way to restrict access to file system **and** network in the same time to the loaded swf ?

Compiler option "-use-network=true|false" does not fit because you cannot restrict both file/network.

Code example :

*Air App* :

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class TestContentSecurity extends Sprite
    {
        private var l :Loader = new Loader;
        public function TestContentSecurity()
        {
            addChild(l);
            l.load(new URLRequest(File.documentsDirectory.nativePath + "/Content.swf"));
        }
    }
}
```

*Loaded swf* :

```
    package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Content extends Sprite
    {
        private var _log : TextField = new TextField;
        private var l: URLLoader;
        public function Content()
        {
            addChild(_log)
            _log.multiline = true;
            _log.width = 500;
            _log.height = 500;
            l = new URLLoader();
            l.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
            l.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
            l.load(new URLRequest("c:/Windows/regedit.exe"))
        }

        public function onLoad(e:Event) : void{
            _log.text += "SUCCESS\n" ;
        }
        public function onError(e:IOErrorEvent) : void{
            _log.text += "ERROR\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The loaded swf is in user's document folder, outside Air app folder. Currently, the loaded swf is abble to load "c:/Windows/regedit.exe" and I don't want it (neither sending informations on the network).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found one solution in AIR, I don't like it but it works. The idea is to have a mini http server and to load content from this server.

I load targeted file with :

`new URLRequest("http://localhost:1111/Content.swf")`

By doing this, flash will load "Content.swf" as a remote file and place it in a REMOTE security sandbox. Loaded swf won't be able to access to any local files neither to network.

If anyone have a cleaner solution to get this REMOTE security sand box, I will be happy.

```
/**
 * HTTP server original idea :
 * http://coenraets.org/blog/2009/12/air-2-0-web-server-using-the-new-server-socket-api/
 */
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
    import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.ServerSocketConnectEvent;
    import flash.net.ServerSocket;
    import flash.net.Socket;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class TestContentSecurity extends Sprite
    {
        private var l :Loader = new Loader;
        private var serverSocket:ServerSocket;

        public function TestContentSecurity()
        {
            init();
            l.load(new URLRequest("http://localhost:1111/Content.swf"));
        }


        private function init():void
        {
            // Initialize the web server directory (in applicationStorageDirectory) with sample files
            listen(1111);
        }

        private function listen(port : uint):void
        {
            try
            {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
                serverSocket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, socketConnectHandler);
                serverSocket.bind(port, "127.0.0.1");
                serverSocket.listen();
                trace("Listening on port " + port + "...\n");
            }
            catch (error:Error)
            {
                trace("Port " + port +
                    " may be in use. Enter another port number and try again.\n(" +
                    error.message +")", "Error");
            }
        }

        private function socketConnectHandler(event:ServerSocketConnectEvent):void
        {
            var socket:Socket = event.socket;
            socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
        }

        private function socketDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            try
            {
                var socket:Socket = event.target as Socket;
                var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                socket.readBytes(bytes);
                var request:String = "" + bytes;

                var filePath:String = request.substring(5, request.indexOf("HTTP/") - 1);
                var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(filePath);
                if (file.exists && !file.isDirectory)
                {
                    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
                    stream.open( file, FileMode.READ );
                    var content:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                    stream.readBytes(content);
                    stream.close();
                    socket.writeUTFBytes("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n");
                    socket.writeUTFBytes("Content-Type: application/x-shockwave-flash\n\n");
                    socket.writeBytes(content);
                }
                else
                {
                    socket.writeUTFBytes("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n");
                    socket.writeUTFBytes("Content-Type: text/html\n\n");
                    socket.writeUTFBytes("<html><body><h2>Page Not Found</h2></body></html>");
                }
                socket.flush();
                socket.close();
            }
            catch (error:Error)
            {
                trace("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you deploy as an AIR application.

You can, however, store *some* data in a [SharedObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html), even when you deploy with `-use-network=true`.  This should work for storing game state and such.

**Edit**:

In AIR, security between content from different domains is regulated by using [AIR sandbox bridges](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e5c.html).  This should give you all the leverage you need.

Comment: This project is an AIR app but I don't see anything that can help me. And I need to forbid network use and local access.

Comment: If an Air app load an Swf file, the loaded file can access to the file system or network, even if I load it into an new ApplicationDomain. can I change SecurityDoamin setting ?

Comment: The AIR app automatically defines the ApplicationDomain.  The loaded SWF is not allowed to access the local file system or set `Security.allowDomain()` (which essentially means: No network access except for the domain the SWF was loaded from), unless you explicitly expose such an API in the `parentSandboxBridge`.

Comment: Air app cannot use Security.allowDomain() (I get SecurityError: Error #3207: Application-sandbox content cannot access this feature.). And my loaded swf can load anything with a simple Loader/UrlLoader

Comment: I will post a snippets tomorrow, think you for your interrest